# Decoding ethereum transaction input function with Golang (go-ethereum in 2023)

Tags: go, ethereum, go-ethereum

I am trying to decode the input data for an ethereum transaction in Golang using the go-ethereum package. I have looked on here, ethereum stack exchange and the Go-ethereum documentation in order to try and help. I've even asked ChatGPT and it can't fix it either.

The error message I receive stems from the rlp package when calling the rlp.DecodeBytes function. The error message received is: rlp: expected input list for []main.SwapFunction.

Here is the transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd918b14504b82d4c5334a751e0439826e682a57c6813f16a707801f89f589b90

And here are my types in my code which correspond to the function being called in the transaction:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rlp"
)

type SwapDescription struct {
    SrcToken         common.Address
    DstToken         common.Address
    SrcReceiver      common.Address
    DstReceiver      common.Address
    Amount           *big.Int
    MinReturnAmount  *big.Int
    GuaranteedAmount *big.Int
    Flags            *big.Int
    Referrer         common.Address
    Permit           []byte
}

type CallDescription struct {
    TargetWithMandatory *big.Int
    GasLimit            *big.Int
    Value               *big.Int
    Data                []byte
}

type SwapFunction struct {
    Caller common.Address
    Desc   SwapDescription
    Calls  []CallDescription
}
```

Here is my code to try and decode the input data into the SwapFunction struct in order to access the fields:

```
func main() {
    // Connect to Ethereum network
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/jsonrpc/MY-API-KEY")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to Ethereum network:", err)
        return
    }

    // Define the transaction hash
    txHash := "0xd918b14504b82d4c5334a751e0439826e682a57c6813f16a707801f89f589b90"

    hash := common.HexToHash(txHash)

    tx, isPending, err := client.TransactionByHash(context.Background(), hash)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    if isPending {
        fmt.Println("Transaction is pending")
        return
    }

    input := tx.Data()

    var functionSignature string
    if len(input) >= 4 {
        functionSignature = string(input[:4])
    }

    fmt.Println("Function signature:", functionSignature)

    var decodedData []SwapFunction
    fmt.Println(decodedData)
    err = rlp.DecodeBytes(input[4:], &decodedData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Decoded data:", decodedData)

}
```

Please can someone show me how to fix the error "rlp: expected input list for []main.SwapFunction?

I have tried changing the decodedData variable to a single SwapFunction and then in the code above, to a slice of SwapFunction.

I am not sure why this error is happening and the documentation in rlp is relatviely vague around this area. I have read the following page: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum@v1.10.26/rlp.

Someone please help as I am at a roadblock. Thank you for anyone who helps and apologies if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your error, but if you want to decode the data you first need to load and parse the ABI of the contract. If you don't have the ABI, there's a chance you can grab it from etherscan. In my example I saved the ABI in a file `abi.json`:

```golang
func loadABI(path string) ([]byte, error) {
    abiData, err := os.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return abiData, nil
}

func parseABI(a []byte) (abi.ABI, error) {
    var parsedABI abi.ABI
    err := json.Unmarshal(a, &parsedABI)
    if err != nil {
        return abi.ABI{}, err
    }
    return parsedABI, nil
}

func main() {
    abiData, err := loadABI("abi.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    parsedABI, err := parseABI(abiData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Then you can decode the data. (I used `input` to store what you call `data`):

```golang
inputBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(input[2:]) // Remove the "0x" prefix before decoding
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to decode string:", err)
}

signature, data := inputBytes[:4], inputBytes[4:] // A byte can represent two hexadecimal characters

method, err := swapABI.MethodById(signature)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var args = make(map[string]interface{})

err = method.Inputs.UnpackIntoMap(args, data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Method: %s\n", method)

for key, value := range args {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %+v\n", key, value)
}
```